# Error Handling in Proc SQL(like try Catch)

Tags: sas

I doing like this

```
libname DZY 'Path';
Proc sql;
select * from DZ.some_table;
run;
```

Here I have to add an error handling like  if something goes wrong in select statement or within the block I have to write error message to an separate text file in the folder. 
This is what I tried

```
%macro sortclass;
 Proc sql;
    select * from DZ.some_table;
    run; 
%if &amp;amp;SQLRC gt 0 %then %goto error;
%error:
proc export data=""
run;

%exit:
%mend; 
%sortclass;
```

I am trying to do an try catch like error handling.., How can do this in effective way. Thanks In advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Base SAS does not have try/catch mechanisms, so an error due to macro generated code can cause problems with attempts to externally log messages.

```
filename logfile 'mysolution.log' mod;

%macro mylogger(message);
  * may fail due to apriori errors;
  data _null_;
    file log;
    put "%superq(message)";
  run;
  * a more advanced version would instead use macro `%sysfunc'd` invocations of
  * `FOPEN FPUT FWRITE FWRITE` to append to a custom external log file;
%mend;

%macro mymacro(...);
   ... some SQL statement(s) ...
   %if &SYSRC > 0 %then %do;
     %mylogger(Failer at step 1); 
     %return;
   %end;
   ... some more SQL statement(s) ...       
   %if &SYSRC > 0 %then %do;
     %mylogger(Failer at step 2); 
     %return;
   %end;
%mend;
```

Note: You can also submit SAS code from java or .net code that uses a SAS workspace session -- search for SAS integrated object model (iom) for more info.  Such a solution would have a rich environment for try/catch/throw and advanced logging models.